# No network access until I ping the gateway

Tags: networking, internet, nginx

I have the weirdest of problems that I can't work out on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I start the machine I cannot access the internet and the machine's nginx server cannot be accessed. Running `ifconfig` reveals that the machine has received an IP address from the DHCP server. However, trying something like `ping google.com` doesn't work. I can't ping the internet router either.

However, if I run `ping 172.16.10.254` which pings the gateway, I can then immediately access the internet and also the server.

Not sure what the problem is...?

--

Content of /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) 
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d: 
#
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d  
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: cat you post the content of interfaces ? `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Can you describe your network organization ? (DHCP, Internet router and gateway)?

Comment: Router is a Draytek Vigor2920 which provides DHCP and access to the Internet. Switch is an HP 2920 (old 3COM switch) which provides routing. I can ping the computer from any other network computer...

Comment: @Archemar `# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
#source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp`

Comment: what are IP of router and switch (if switch has an IP) ?

Comment: router: 172.16.20.1
switch: 172.16.20.254

Answer (score 1):

I have now the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on a Proxmox hypervisor.

The only workaround I could figure out is to add a ping command to crontab that pings 2 packages in each minutes since it seems to me as the network interface goes to sleep when it is not used for a short while. However this seems very unlikely since there are several virtual webservers hosted on this server and someone is using it almost every minute...

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/ping -c 2 192.168.30.1 > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is certainly in your HP 2920 configuration (since it has an IP address of it's own, it should be configurable). It's a kind of dial on demand behaviour. Check particularly the `spawning tree` option (if exist) and try to disable it. It is useless on little networks and works bad with some computers.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I don't think it is, although I did try changing the settings. I have another ubuntu machine that doesn't have any problems. On the same network and everything.

Comment: If so, I would exchange the (physical) connection of the two machines (if possible).

Comment: They're both virtual machines on the same ESXi host!

Comment: This is a crucial point you should have explained earlier !!! :-) The VM configurations are a part of the problem. But, sorry, I don't know much about VMWare...

Comment: Both configs are the same! What should I look for?

Comment: I gave you all the ideas I have ! Sorry ! Being not in front of the machine, I don't know how to help further.